# Working out elapsed time from two columns in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have two rows stored in a table called client_booking. These are called start_time and end_time. I need to create a text box in ORACLE APEX which generates the elapsed time through an SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time difference being in days, let us multiply it by no of hours 24 and no of minutes 60. Assuming they are of `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` datatypes

```
select (
         to_date('01-01-2014 '|| end_time  ||'00','DD-MM-YYYY HHMISS') -
         to_date('01-01-2014 '|| start_time||'00','DD-MM-YYYY HHMISS')
       ) * 24 * 60 as time_elapsed_in_mins
from your_table;
```

Comment: -1 I'm confused by the `MAX()` and `MIN()` calls, because the OP said that the data is in the columns start_time and end_time

Comment: @Erick I afraid OP meant it as 2 rows!! You can click the edit link in my answer too!!

Comment: I think he meant "columns", because I have a hard time believing he had two rows named start_time and end_time. :)

Comment: apologies here. I did mean column not row, it's also worth mentioning the time is stored as '1130' not '11:30'. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2151140 just time you have ?I updated my answer.. I initially assumed it asxolumns, but after readingyour question,  i changed..